# Uses of 「四つ角」in quizlet as intersection？

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am making my way through a very large quizlet flashcard deck that has already had a few mistakes that I have caught. I just came across[ 四つ角]{よつかど} which it lists as intersection and shows a picture of a four-way intersection. This deck also already has [交差点]{こうさてん} listed as intersection which most of the internet seems to agree with.

I was wondering if anyone knows if [四つ角]{よつかど} is actually used, and if so to refer to what. Google translate says it means "four corners", so that got me thinking it might specifically refer to four way intersection?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? What made you doubt the meaning?

Comment: what made me doubt the meaning was the Google translation and a post on a different website that said (in japanese) "we don't use よつかど). I am also more concerned I guess with the differences in uses between the two words. when using jisho, 交差点 just shows up as intersection but 四つ角　also has four corners and street corner in its definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 四つ角 is a real word recognized by almost everyone, although it's a little dated word and 十字路 is more popular these days.

Common words are:

- 交差点: intersection in general

  - 十字路, 四つ角: Looks like `＋`
  - 三叉路: three-forked intersection

    - Y字路: Looks like `Ｙ`
    - T字路, 丁字路: Looks like `Ｔ`

Rare words such as 三つ角 and 五叉路 also exist, but their meanings are self-explanatory once you've mastered the common ones.

When you have doubts about word usage, a corpus is more reliable. According to [BCCWJ](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/), 十字路 is roughly four times more popular than 四つ角, and 四つ角 tends to be preferred by older novelists.